# How can I disable a part of the screen in X.Org

Tags: linux, xorg, i3

I'm running a Laptop with Arch Linux, X.org and i3. Due to a broken LCD panel, I would like to disable/ignore the left ~228 Pixels of the screen until I have time to get it repaired.

So far, I've tried using a non-standard resolution and then adding an offset, but had no success. Is there any simple solution for this?

Comment: I thank `xrandr` can do it, just not sure of the exact options.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127911/due-to-a-broken-monitor-i-need-to-setup-only-the-right-half-of-my-screen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `xrandr`.

I have tested this breathy on a single monitor.

First look at current resolution and subtract 228 from X. Replace X and Y below for new resolutions Y=y, X=x-228. (note in the text below lower case x is a literal x). Run `xrandr` to get output name.

Then `xrandr  --fb XxY --output OUTPUT_NAME --transform 1,0,-228,0,1,0,0,0,1`

Comment: Would be nice to add how to revert this :)