# Can I configure Linux to use a subsection of my monitor?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, resolution, hdmi

I have a monitor that has a defect (red star) in a lower section, is it possible to contain the screen to the section above this defect?

[image]

I have tried setting the overscan_bottom in /boot/config.txt, but it seems to shrink the the page horizontally (in addition to the intended direction, vertically) trying to preserve the aspect ratio of the resolution, is my guess.

I believe the monitor is 1920x1080, I don't mind going down to a lower resolution because it's for an arcade game emulator.

I am using HDMI output

The OS is Raspbian.

Comment: If you are using xorg, you can use xrandr to solve that. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144692/how-can-i-disable-a-part-of-the-screen-in-x-org).