# Reduce used display size for both X server and console

Tags: kernel, tty, display

I have the situation that I have a LCD display that I would like to use but I want to have a "black unused frame" around the displayed content. Is there a kernel setting which controls the used dimensions of the detected screen?

Comment: You can perform screen transformation with `xrandr`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/127911/80886 for related problem.

Comment: Hey jimmij, thanks for the answer. That should work for the X server. Do you happen to know if that's also possible for the linux console (where no X server needs to be running)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't.