# use specific part of the monitor

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, display

my screen is half damaged, and i can't replace it because of the current condition.
i wish to find a way to disable the display from the damaged area, like using the monitor as 1500x1080 float to the left..[image]

my os is Ubuntu 20.04

---

what it have tried:

```
mz37@mz37-pc:~$ cvt 1495 1080 60
# 1496x1080 59.92 Hz (CVT) hsync: 67.11 kHz; pclk: 134.75 MHz
Modeline "1496x1080_60.00"  134.75  1496 1600 1752 2008  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync

mz37@mz37-pc:~$ gtf 1496 1080 60 -x
# 1496x1080 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 67.08 kHz; pclk: 134.70 MHz
Modeline "1496x1080_60.00"  134.70  1496 1592 1752 2008  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync

mz37@mz37-pc:~$ xrandr  --newmode "1496x1080_60.00" 134.70  1496 1592 1752 2008  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
mz37@mz37-pc:~$ xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1496x1080_60.00"
```

i have resized my display but it's aligned to the center and i want it to be the the right

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Due to a broken monitor, I need to setup only the right half of my screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127911/due-to-a-broken-monitor-i-need-to-setup-only-the-right-half-of-my-screen)

Comment: i succeed to make display `1496x1080` but i cant move it from the center to the right, the transform is not good

Comment: If you update your question with the actual command and output, we might be able to help.